# How to generate frontend code for an existing app using JHipster?

Tags: spring-boot, generator, microservices, jhipster

We have an existing backend with microservices for our native apps. Now we need a support and admin UI, therefore my question, is JHipster the right generator for that and if yes, how can I create entities from my existing databases? Most of them are MySQL? As I understood I need a JDL but do I need to create it manually?

Thanks!

Comment: You should change your title as it is primarily opinion-based and people will close it. My understanding of you question is more "How to generate frontend code for an existing app using JHipster?"

Answer (score 3):

JHipster has no support for generating code on top of existing databases. So, you would probably have to write manually JDL for your existing entities, it can be very difficult or impossible depending on the conventions you used for naming your tables, columns and relations.
There's a module that can help to some extent https://github.com/bastienmichaux/generator-jhipster-db-helper.

However if you plan to generate only frontend code, it could be simpler because you would not depend on database structure. The effort for connecting your generated frontend to your existing backend would depend mainly on which authentication type its uses and REST API it exposes.

Just build a prototype: generate frontend only with `jhipster --skip-server`, write a JDL file for few entities and then import it, then see how you can modify code to adapt to your backend.